# Implementing tooltip in a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-design-system

I want to position the tooltip according to the hovered element. How can I do this in lightning without using jquery?

Comment: Are you using Lightning tag because from Spring 17 many Lightning component have title tag this https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_lightning_components.htm?edition=&impact=

Comment: @TusharSharma Is there any way to customize contents of title attribute of the lightning tags? thanks.

Comment: Yes you can add your own message.

Comment: @TusharSharma I am really sorry that I was not clear before. Can I add markup to the title attribute? This is where I am having problems. thanks.

Comment: Nope. You'd need to create your own title substitute with JavaScript.

Answer (score 11):

**Update:**

Note that now salesforce provides out of box component [lightning:helptext](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:helptext/specification) which provides pop up and help text .

You can roll your own version of the tooltip component where you can change positions and styling as per your need

Here is a simple example

**tooltip.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
<div class="slds-form-element">
   <div class="slds-form-element__icon slds-align-middle" onmouseover="{!c.display}" onmouseout="{!c.displayOut}">
      <button class="slds-button slds-button slds-button--icon" aria-describedby="help" title="Help" >
         <lightning:icon iconName="utility:info" size="xx-small" alternativeText="Help"/>
         <span class="slds-assistive-text">Help</span>
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="slds-popover slds-popover--tooltip slds-nubbin--left-top toggle" role="tooltip" id="help" style="position:absolute;top:-4px;left:20px;" aura:id="tooltip">
   <div class="slds-popover__body">Sit nulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecat. Nostrud ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi.</div>
</div>  
</aura:component>
```

**tooltipController.js**

```
({
  display : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.toggleHelper(component, event);
  },

  displayOut : function(component, event, helper) {
   helper.toggleHelper(component, event);
  }
})
```

**tooltipHelper.js**

```
({
   toggleHelper : function(component,event) {
    var toggleText = component.find("tooltip");
    $A.util.toggleClass(toggleText, "toggle");
   }
})
```

**tooltip.css**

```
/*toggleCss.css*/
 .THIS.toggle {
   display: none;
 }
```

The application can be created to test this

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
   <c:tooltip/>
</aura:application>
```

[image]

[image]

Please note this is a draft and you can further create attributes and generalise few things like text and position .

Note that you can change various positions of tooltip based on the class

> .slds-nubbin--left, .slds-nubbin--left-top, .slds-nubbin--left-bottom, .slds-nubbin--top-left, .slds-nubbin--top-right, .slds-nubbin--right-top, .slds-nubbin--right-bottom, .slds-nubbin--bottom-left, .slds-nubbin--bottom-right.

Comment: This works. But is there any way to change the offset of the tooltip with pure or SF javascript.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean by offset . Lightning components uses JavaScript and CSS so the core logic remains same

Comment: The tootip should move with pointer.

Comment: On a similar note, how would you offset the nubbin by a certain number of pixels? For example, you have desire `bottom-right`, but if your icon is close to the left of the screen, that would cause the tooltip to be off the screen (-x). Let's say that `bottom` wasn't desired, how would you get the nubbin to `bottom-right` - 10px for example? It's tricky since there's a pseudo-class and the only way I can see it do this is to add CSS, which is much trickier than being able to use JS to manipulate the DOM elements directly.

Answer (score 1):

Seems a bit old question but here is how I just implemented this, basically you can place this line above your lightning input element and it will have a label and a helptext tooltip.

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread">
   <label class="slds-form-element__label slds-text-heading_label">Text Label </label>
   <lightning:helptext iconName="utility:info" content="Some help text" />    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce provides its own standard tooltip component. So no need to write lots of UI/UX.

here is the example

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:helptext

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a [related post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144663/how-to-add-tooltips-to-lightninginput-components/251670#251670)

"fieldLevelHelp" attribute works for lightning:input component too even though it's not been documented. It's documented for lightning-input and aura components use LWC under the covers.

You can also create your own field with custom rendering using the below code without the need for any CSS:

`<lightning:layoutItem>
 <span class="slds-form-element">
     <label for="textInput" 
            class="slds-form-element__label slds-no-flex">
         Custom Label
     </label>
     <lightning:helptext content="{!v.fieldLevelHelp}" />
     <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-grow">
         <!--Custom rendered element -->
         <a id="textInput" 
            target="_blank" 
            href="{/lightning/r/'+v.recordId + '/view'}"> 
            Custom Link Label
         </a>
     </div>
</span>
</lightning:layoutItem>`